# How do I remove padding from both sides of Highcharts area category chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

There's too much padding on either side of the area chart and minPadding/maxPadding doesn't work with categories.

I want the area chart to start and end without any padding.

[image]

My code is below:

http://jsfiddle.net/nx4xeb4k/1/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
  chart: {
    type: 'area',
    inverted: false
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Too Much Padding On Either Side'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      fillOpacity: 0.1
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Data Point'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}</b> points'
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Visits',
    data: [
      ["Monday", 58],
      ["Tuesday", 65],
      ["Wednesday", 55],
      ["Thursday", 44],
      ["Friday", 56],
      ["Saturday", 65],
      ["Sunday", 69]
    ],
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false,
      rotation: -90,
      color: '#FFFFFF',
      align: 'right',
      format: '{point.y:.1f}',
      y: 10,
      style: {
        fontSize: '14px',
        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
      }
    }
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A colleague of mine solved this very situation for some of my charts. Their solution was to remove the `type: 'category'` from the x-axis (making it a `linear` type instead) and instead replace the axis labels from an array.

Here's what's been changed:

First, I added an array of your x-axis labels.

```
var categoryLabels = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday",
"Saturday","Sunday"];
```

Next, I updated your series values to hold only the y-axis values.

```
series: [{
  name: 'Visits',
  data: [58, 65, 55, 44, 56, 65, 69],
```

Then, for your x-axis, I included a `formatter` function to pull in the labels from the array as substitutes for the default linear values.

```
xAxis: {
  labels: {
    formatter: function(){
      return categoryLabels[this.value];
    }
  }
},
```

Lastly, I updated the `tooltip` options to show the values from the labels array.

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return categoryLabels[this.x] + ': ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,0);
        }
    },
```

I updated your fiddle with this tweaks: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/nx4xeb4k/4/

I hope you'll find this solution as useful as I have!

[image]

Comment: This is exactly the solution I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

According to [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickmarkPlacement), the default value of `highcharts.xAxis.tickmarkPlacement` is `between` and this is why the point of each category drops between two ticks on `xAxis` in your chart.

By setting `highcharts.xAxis.tickmarkPlacement` to `on` and playing around the value of `highcharts.xAxis.min` and `highcharts.xAxis.max` like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wiltsc/nx4xeb4k/5/), you should be able to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the min / max values to fix the problem.

```
var categoryLabels = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]; 
//....
xAxis: {
  min: 0.49,
  max: categoryLabels.length - 1.49,
  categories: categoryLabels, 
  type: 'category'
},
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/fo04m7k7/